# How do I enable dual boot after Windows 7 Reinstall with no cd?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, disk

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu via the internet. No CD was involved. After I reinstalled Win 7 due to issues with it, my dual boot disappeared.  I do not have the option of using Live CD or whatever.  My system does not have an optical drive and my current situation prevents me from getting one (deployed military)  How can I fix Ubuntu?

Comment: If you installed from inside Windows did you install wubi. That is just a file inside the Windows NTFS partition and uses the Windows boot loader. Only if you installed to a second NTFS partition may you still have wubi and then could update Windows BCD to boot that install.

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstalled Windows, it took over your MBR with it's own boot loader.  Your Ubuntu is still fine you just need to restore GRUB so you can dual boot.  You want to use [a tool called `boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

EDIT:

With no optical drive, your best bet is to boot a live distro via USB.  For this, [download an Ubuntu iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and then [flash it to the USB as a bootable image using Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).  This is my preference when rescuing systems using a "live CD."  It allows you to get the same effect using a disc or requiring an optical drive.

Comment: like is said i do not have access to using a cd

Comment: You can't fix it from within Windows unless you reinstall your Ubuntu using Wubi.  You should download and burn a CD

Comment: @TyeMoore has no access to CDs. He just stated that.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Ok, now I feel dumb.  I need to read closer :-O.  The same effect can be achieved with a bootable USB drive.  See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a USB flash drive of at least 1GB capacity
2. [Create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) by writing a [new Ubuntu image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on it.
3. Boot Ubuntu using this new flashdrive.
4. Install and run [the `boot-repair` tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score -1):

If you can boot from USB, your answer is [there](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

If your machine has room for more than one HD, and you can borrow one for some time, you can set up the temp HD as primary, install Ubuntu on it and fix the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) from there. Hello screwdriver, hello headheache, but in the end it will be fine.